# Who lives in 314?

Tags: riddle, cipher, visual, steganography, music

[image: aoPrk]

You've been invited to room 314, but who lives in 314?

Hint 1:

> Room 314 is the last door at the end of the hall.

Hint 2:

> As you listen at the door, you can hear someone playing an instrument

Hint 3:

> The neighbor's door has a post-it note stuck to it with the question "Why does the sun shine?"

Comment: Way too short to even be a partial answer, but the image footnote reference is 2, rather than the standard 1. Together with the room number that might mean something, using 1-4 together.

Comment: How about the fact that the QR's are not of equal size, and the 314 print on the door looks distorted? Does this relate to the stenography tag?

Comment: It's pi: 3.14.. turning the knob describes the circle.

Comment: @rocksteady it is not pi.  Pi doesn't fit with the `music` tag.

Comment: pi is math and music and life and everything else ;)  But OK, I agree.

Comment: So.. do we get another hint at some point? I do believe we are stumped!

Comment: @TJames Ask and ye shall receive.

Comment: Piano starts with "pi"

Comment: I'm guessing we'll never know?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I've added another hint.  Also noteworthy, each hint is actually 2 hints, from a certain point of view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I got even close is through the work of everyone else here, and I'm really just piecing together things everyone else has said so consider this a "group solve", but I believe the answer is:

> Dr. Worm (a song by They Might be Giants). Everything is a reference to lyrics from that song.

The QR codes say:

> A REAL ONE I AM NOT
>  YET REAL I AM

Well:

> The lyrics for Dr. worm say:
>  I'm not a real doctor,
>  But I am a real worm;

The QR codes also say:

> Just come turn the knob
>  and things get interesting

and

> Dr. Worm lyrics:
>  I'm interested in things.

How the clues fit in:

clue 1:

> Last door at the end of the hall

explanation:

> The last letter of the clues for each QR code are TMBG - initials for They Might Be Giants.

clue 2:

> As you listen at the door, you can hear someone playing an instrument

explanation:

> I like to play the drums.

clue 3:

> The neighbor's door has a post-it note stuck to it with the question "Why does the sun shine?"

explanation:

> Another song by TMBG

original hint 1:

> There's also a doorbell, but no one answered when you pushed it.

explanation:

> I'll leave the front un-locked 'cause I can't Hear the doorbell

original hint 2:

> They really seem to enjoy banging those drums!

explanation:

> I like to play the drums.

original hint 3:

> Istanbul/Constantinople

explanation:

> Another song by TMBG

Comment: It's already been answered by puzzle-guesser but thank you for your effort.

Comment: "Last door at the end of the hall" is meant to direct you to look at the endings.

Comment: @DavidStarkey oh, got it. edited in.

Comment: @Gh0sT Puzzle guesser's post has no connection between the puzzle and the answer - it's based solely off a guess based on the clues (per the post).

Comment: I agree.  This answer is more complete, as it works through the connection from the actual puzzle contents to the answer.  If someone knew the lyrics to this song very well, they could get from the puzzle to the answer.

Answer (score 19):

## Partial answer

If you decode every QR code using something like  [zxing.org](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx), you get  these codes (top to bottom):

### 1

> `nmi ztia, Q pu`
>  Vigenere Cipher with key "PI":
>  `YET REAL I AM`

### 2

> `bonk eht nrut emoc tsuJ`
>  Inverse the string:
>   `Just come turn the knob`

### 3

> `YW5kIHRoaW5ncyBnZXQgaW50ZXJlc3Rpbmc=`
>  From base-64:
>  `and things get interesting`

### 4

> `N erny bar, V nz abg`
>  Rot 13:
>  `A REAL ONE I AM NOT`

## Credits

Gareth McCaughan♦ spotted a mistake.

Comment: There are a lot of things related to circles. `PI` as the Vignere key, room 314 (`3.14...`), turn the knob (the knob would be the radius and turning it would create 1/4 of a circle), a real one (pi is irrational but a real number)

Comment: I'm guessing you need to answer the final question of "who lives there". It's obvious from the clues you got (and @andrewtweber's hint).

Comment: @Bachrach44 I'm not sure it's obvious... Mr. Circle? Mr. Pi? :) I also don't know what the clue "and things get intereting" means. There's probably something I'm not noticing.

Comment: @R.M Perhaps I'm being overly simplistic, but I would just assume the answer is "pi".

Comment: @Bachrach44 The answer is not pi.  There's a couple things that haven't been noticed yet.

Comment: But what does the "music" tag indicate?  I vote for A Perfect Circle ;)

Comment: Having both steganography and music tag.. maybe there is a music file hidden in the image? I'm not using my computer now so I can't investigate further.

Comment: Is the missing 's' in `and things get intereting` deliberate or a typo?

Comment: @Tom there might be something going on with the letters, since "things" have a few letters in common with "intereting". -hs +intere ("in there"? - a bit of a stretch). I don't really know.

Comment: Just checked myself, it indeed is missing an 's'. Could be a typo by the OP though. @DavidStarkey

Comment: @Tom That would be a typo

Answer (score 18):

## Another partial answer because I can't comment

The image's `alt` attribute is aoPrk, so going to https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoPrk.png, we see the order of the qr codes.

Plugging in the decoded words from R.M's answer, we see

> A REAL ONE I AM NOT
>  YET REAL I AM
>  Just come turn the knob
>  and things get interesting

No clue where to go from here.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it i or $\sqrt{-1}$

1.

> YET REAL I AM A REAL ONE I AM NOT
>  This similar to complex numbers as they are not "real numbers"

2.

> The room number is 314
>  This is one part of eulers identity 
>  $e^{i\pi} = -1$
>  This again uses complex numbers

3.

> The words "just come turn the knob and things get interesting"
>  Probably alludes to multiplication by $i$ rotates something $90^{\circ}$ on the complex plane

Credits to R.M. for decoding QR codes

Comment: You could even say that "I live in room 314".

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm not sure how it fits with the `music` tag.

Answer (score 4):

## Another partial answer

At first, I was planning to post this in comment, but I think it's better to write as partial answer for sharing.

When I was checking edit history of this one, I found that OP wrote some comments when update hints.

For Hint 1,

> There's also a doorbell, but no one answered when you pushed it.

For Hint 2,

> They really seem to enjoy banging those drums!

Last, for Hint 3

> There's also a flag down the hall for Istanbul....or maybe Constantanople?

And I assume that OP had make another typo in hints again. :)

Comment: You are correct.  I am terrible at spell.

Answer (score 4):

Is the occupant of 314:

> Dan Hickey, drummer for They Might be Giants from 1997 to 2003?

Guess is based on:

> These clues: Istanbul (Not Constantinople), Why Does the Sun Shine, drumming

Guess is not based on:

> Anything in the original puzzle.  No clue how the original puzzle without the clues would lead to this answer.

Updated Guess:

> Based on last clue in comments below, I believe Dr. Worm lives in Room 314.  Full credit to all the other clues and guesses that led to this answer.

Comment: Close.  Perhaps a song about a certain dirt-dwelling critter of theirs will help out?

Comment: Good job! I agree with you the original puzzle is unsolvable.

Comment: @Gh0sT Perhaps I overestimated the popularity of the song, but I believe the puzzle to be solvable without the assistance of the hints.

Comment: After discovering the full answer, I agree.  I was not familiar with the song lyrics, but someone who is could get from the puzzle to the answer directly.  PopularIsn'tRight has a more complete and correct answer.